# The process of uploading a file to Google drive prevents the program from deleting the file afterwards

Tags: python, windows

For some reason, the program won't remove the file. I think it's because of the uploading process, but I don't know how to fix it.

Open this link(to get the API Access_Token): https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth/oauthchooseaccount?redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fdevelopers.google.com%2Foauthplayground&prompt=consent&response_type=code&client_id=407408718192.apps.googleusercontent.com&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fdrive&access_type=offline&flowName=GeneralOAuthFlow

This link works in Brave web browser or else you need to be administrator.

Then paste the Access_Token you find after clicking the blue button where it says: {Access_token}

```
#alle modules
import os
import json
import requests

#create file
t = open('Test.txt', 'w')
t.write('This is a test file')
t.close()

#upload zip file to Google Drive
headers = {"Authorization": "Bearer {Access_Token}"}
para = {
    "name": "Test.txt"}
files = {
    'data': ('metadata', json.dumps(para), 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'),
    'file': open("./Test.txt", "rb")}
r = requests.post(
    "https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files?uploadType=multipart",
    headers=headers,
    files=files)

print(r.text)
os.remove('Test.txt')
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Is this on Windows? If so, `r` probably still has a file handle open on the file, in which case Windows would not let you delete the file. You need to make sure all file handles are closed before you can delete the file.

Comment: Actually, yes, the file is open, you still have the handle in `files["file"]`.

Comment: Yes, this is windows and this has fixed my problem. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will assume you are running on Windows, because on that operating system you cannot delete a file if there is any file handle open on it anywhere, and that's your problem here.

You have opened a file handle to `Test.txt` and stored in in `files["file"]`, and you need to close it before you can delete the file.

So this should solve your issue:

```
files["file"].close()
os.remove('Test.txt')
```

Comment: If this indeed fixes your problem, then your question is a not-so-obvious duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/70116608/3216427 since the solution is the same.

Comment: I had been looking for the solution, but this one never showed up in the list of similar problems. What I was doing wrong was, I putted 'files.close()'. Never thought I was so close.

Comment: Yeah, I knew of this one since I answered it a week ago, but I looked for a good duplicate to use instead, and I didn't find a canonical one. I'm sure there are many different questions where this is the underlying problem, but each is likely to face the problem from a different angle, or from a different programming language.